# IPTABLES rule not blocking

Tags: linux, iptables

I've been trying to learn about Iptables. I've looked at a few sources and they say that I can block a subnet by doing something like

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.3.0/24 -j DROP
```

which leaves me with something like,

```
iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 
DROP       all  --  192.168.3.0/24       anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  192.168.3.0/24       anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-SSH (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

However traffic from that subnet is still getting through.

http://pastebin.com/VNjJxJyM

Why? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule is correct if you want to block outgoing traffic from the firewall machine (originated from firewall machine itself) which does not make much sense to block subnet originating from one machine!!

I think you want to block traffic coming from some subnet and getting through the firewall. In this case, you need to add the rule to the `FORWARD` chain NOT to the `OUTPUT` chain.

Here is the rule:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.3.0/24 -j DROP
```

Comment: Shouldn't iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.3.0/24 -j DROP be also added?

Comment: @EricDANNIELOU: So, this will deny any access to the firewall machine from the same subnet.